# How to get a zero matrix from matrix multiplication.

Tags: matrices

Let $A = \left[ \begin{matrix} 3 & 2 & 1\\ 5 & 0  &1\end{matrix}\right]$,

how can I know if there is a matrix $N$ , st. $AN=0$ (N is not a zero matrix)

Comment: The columns of A are linearly dependent.

Comment: I can't see that.

Comment: 5*last column - second column = first column. Anyways, in two dimensional space, you cannot have three independent vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to solve 
$$A\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3} = \pmatrix{0\\0}$$

> in the question they demand $N$ be at least two columns.

And it doesn't matter how many columns $N$ should have. Say, from the above equation, you found a 3-element column vector $\mathbf x \ne \pmatrix{0&0&0}^T$ such that

$$A\mathbf x = \pmatrix{0\\0}$$

Then there would exist a $3\times j$ matrix $N = \mathbf x\pmatrix{c_1&c_2&\cdots&c_j}$, $c_1, \ldots, c_j\in\mathbb R$, such that

$$\begin{align*}
AN &= A\mathbf x\pmatrix{c_1&c_2&\cdots&c_j}\\
&= \pmatrix{0\\0}\pmatrix{c_1&c_2&\cdots&c_j}\\
&= \pmatrix{0&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&\cdots&0}
\end{align*}$$

> Okay, another question. Is it possible to find matrix $N$ such that $AN$ and $NA$ are zero matrices of their respective dimensions, without $N$ being the zero matrix?

Similarly, try to solve
$$\begin{align*}
\pmatrix{y_1&y_2} A &= \pmatrix{0&0&0}\\
A^T \pmatrix{y_1\\y_2} &= \pmatrix{0\\0\\0}
\end{align*}$$

If there were one solution of non-zero row vector $\mathbf y^T$ that satisfies $\mathbf y^T A = \pmatrix{0&0&0}$, then can you construct an $N$ from $\mathbf y^T$ and $\mathbf x$ that satisfies your condition? And if you were not able to find such non-zero $\mathbf y^T$, can you reason that no non-zero $N$ would satisfy $NA = 0$?

If you notice, trying to find non-trivial solution for $\pmatrix{y_1&y_2}A = \pmatrix{0&0&0}$ can be considered as trying to determine whether the rows of $A$ are dependent. Can you see from $A$ if that is the case?

Comment: in the question they demand $N$ be at least two columns.

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani: Once you have a single nonzero column, you can add as many zero columns as you like. Or repeat the column you found. Or multiply it by a scalar and add that as a new column. Since $(1,1,-5,)$ gives the only relation between the columns, up to a common scalar factor, any answer will actually be of this form.

Comment: Okay, another question. Is it possible to find matrix $N$ such that $AN=NA=0$ without $N$ being the zero matrix?

Comment: Say such $N$ exists. Would $AN$ and $NA$ have the same dimension?

Comment: number of $N$ columns can be minimum 2 and maximum 4
number of $N$ rows can be minimum 2 and maximum 4

Comment: Consider that the dimension of $A$ is $2\times 3$. How many rows should $N$ have if $AN$ is valid? How many columns should $N$ have if $NA$ is valid?

Answer (score 1):

In this case there is a theorem that guarantees the existence of such an $N$ (of size $3 \times 1)$, because the matrix $A$ has more columns than rows.

Comment: what is this theorem? and how do I Find $N$? can u show an example ?!

Comment: Do you know a theorem about sufficient conditions for a homogeneous system of linear equations to have a nontrivial solution?

Comment: I don't know if we are talking about the same thing, but there is a way of solving this in case I can find a linear relation between the columns.

Comment: Well, yes you are right. Finding a nontrivial linear relation between the columns will give you a matrix $N$ that works. What I am saying is that the fact that the matrix $A$ is $2 \times 3$ means that such a relation *must* exist. That way, if you are only interested in knowing whether $N$ *exists*, without necessarily finding *N*, you obtain the answer immediately. It seemed to me that this was your question.

Comment: yeah you're right. my question sounded like that. But your answer surely helps too.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what could you say about the columns of such a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Let $N = \pmatrix{x_1 & x_2 \\ x_3 & x_4 \\ x_5 & x_6}$.

If you mutiply $A$ and $N$ you will get 4 equations with 6 variables. If you let any 2 of these variables be non-zero, you will get the system of 4 equations with 4 variables. When you solve it, you will get the elements of your matrix and some of them will be non-zero.